# Bash Autocompletion - Insert words in commands

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I know that linux bash has autocompletion feature when TAB is pressed and it will show possible completions just below the command. My question is how can you update autocomplete feature so that in addition to showing the list it would also insert the possible completion by subsequent tabs?

For example,

```
$ sudo apt-[TAB]
```

would show a list like this:

```
apt-add-repository, apt-cdrom ,apt-extracttemplates,apt-get
```

What I want is on next <kbd>Tab</kbd> press it should modify the command to:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository
```

On the next <kbd>Tab</kbd> press the command would show -

```
$ sudo apt-cdrom
```

How to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179642/how-can-i-make-bash-tab-completion-behave-like-vim-tab-completion-and-cycle-thro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `TAB: menu-complete` line to `~/.inputrc` for example with the following command.

```
echo TAB: menu-complete >> ~/.inputrc
```

Logout and logon again.

Comment: Yes. menu-complete iterates through the possible matches but it no longer shows the list of all possible matches. What I want is that on first Tab it would show me a list of all possible matches and on subsequent Tab presses it would iterate through them like menu-complete